# AWS Schema Converstion Tool Microsoft SQL Server driver path

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, amazon-aurora, aws-sct

I'm trying to use the AWS Schema Conversion Tool to migrate a SQL Server database to Aurora/PostgreSQL.  I get asked for the Microsoft SQL Server driver path.  I've downloaded the Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.4 for SQL Server.  I then browse to mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar and choose it but the AWS Schema Conversion Tool doesn't seem to recognize it.  Is there some other file that I should be using for the Microsoft SQL Server driver path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to download the driver from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Installing.html#CHAP_Installing.JDBCDrivers